# HTTP Error 500 - Apache2 - Aliased Directory

Tags: apache, http, apache2

I have this in my httpd.conf . I have no problem accessing index.php and the PHP code works fine inside it, however classes.php -another file I have in the same directory gives me a HTTP Error 500.

```
Alias /serv /home/will/Dropbox/Business/serv
<Directory /home/will/Dropbox/Business/serv/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually an error with the PHP code.

If you are getting this error but are not sure why it is probably because you have a syntax error of some sort. It seems that if display_errors is turned off in php.ini apache will simple return a 500 error. Navigate to /etc/php5/apache2 and find display_errors in php.ini and switch it to "On". Your page should now tell you what sort of PHP error you are getting and will not simply return a 500.